# The recycler view in my fragment is causing the animations to look choppy

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, android-room

My app is a dictionary app. I am using a room database to save the recent queries in my app. I am showing all the contents of the room database inside my recycler view. When the user searches for a word, the user is taken to the result fragment and the query is added to the room database behind the scenes. It also plays a slide in from right animation when the new fragment is getting added. On pressing the back or the up button, it should take you back with an animation the top level fragment, the main fragment. But the problem I am facing is that something with the recycler view makes that animation look very choppy.

**This is how it should look**: https://i.imgur.com/vdOtA2Y.mp4

**This is how it looks**: https://i.imgur.com/OKpDj7G.mp4

I am pasting the fragment with the recycler view, viewmodel and the recycler view adapter here and I am also pasting a link to the whole app's github repo https://github.com/sbeve72/JADA

```
package com.sbeve.jada.fragments.main

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation
import android.view.animation.Animation
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialAlertDialogBuilder
import com.sbeve.jada.R
import com.sbeve.jada.activities.MainActivity
import com.sbeve.jada.databinding.FragmentMainBinding
import com.sbeve.jada.recyclerview_utils.RecentQueriesAdapter
import com.sbeve.jada.retrofit_utils.RetrofitInit


class MainFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_main), RecentQueriesAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
    private val navController: NavController by lazy {
        this.findNavController()
    }

    //the currently running instance of the activity
    private val mainActivityContext: MainActivity by lazy {
        activity as MainActivity
    }
    private val stayInPlaceAnimation: Animation? by lazy {
        val anim: Animation = AlphaAnimation(1.0F, 1.0F)
        anim.duration = 150
        anim
    }

    private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()

    private lateinit var fragmentMainBinding: FragmentMainBinding

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        fragmentMainBinding = FragmentMainBinding.bind(view)
        fragmentMainBinding.queriesRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(mainActivityContext)

        fragmentMainBinding.currentLanguage.text = RetrofitInit.supportedLanguages.first[mainActivityContext.savedLanguageIndex]
        fragmentMainBinding.changeLanguageGearIcon.setOnClickListener {
            createChangeLanguageDialog().show()
        }
        fragmentMainBinding.searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {

                //work
                viewModel.addQuery(mainActivityContext.savedLanguageIndex, query)
                navController.navigate(MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToResultFragment(query))
                hideSoftKeyboard()
                return true
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?) = false
        })
        setAdapter()
    }

    override fun onCreateAnimation(transit: Int, enter: Boolean, nextAnim: Int) = stayInPlaceAnimation

    private fun createChangeLanguageDialog() =
        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(mainActivityContext)
            .setTitle(getString(R.string.choose_a_language))
            .setSingleChoiceItems(RetrofitInit.supportedLanguages.first, mainActivityContext.savedLanguageIndex)
            { dialogInterface, i ->
                fragmentMainBinding.currentLanguage.text = RetrofitInit.supportedLanguages.first[i]
                mainActivityContext.applicationSharedPreferences
                    .edit()
                    .putInt(getString(R.string.language_setting_key), i)
                    .apply()
                dialogInterface.dismiss()
            }
            .create()

    //hides the keyboard
    private fun hideSoftKeyboard() {
        val imm: InputMethodManager = mainActivityContext.getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager

        //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
        var view = mainActivityContext.currentFocus

        //If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
        if (view == null) {
            view = View(activity)
        }
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }


    private fun setAdapter() {
        viewModel.allQueries.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            val adapter = RecentQueriesAdapter(it, this)
            fragmentMainBinding.queriesRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
        }
    }

    override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
        val queryText = viewModel.allQueries.value!![position].queryText
        navController.navigate(MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToResultFragment(queryText))
    }
}
```

```
package com.sbeve.jada.fragments.main

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.sbeve.jada.myApplication
import com.sbeve.jada.retrofit_utils.RetrofitInit
import com.sbeve.jada.room_utils.DictionaryDatabase
import com.sbeve.jada.room_utils.DictionaryDatabaseDAO
import com.sbeve.jada.room_utils.RecentQuery
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers.IO
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext

class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private var roomDatabase = DictionaryDatabase.getInstance(myApplication.getInstance())

    private val databaseDao: DictionaryDatabaseDAO = roomDatabase.getDao()

    val allQueries = databaseDao.getAllQueries()

    fun addQuery(languageIndex: Int, query: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            withContext(IO) {
                val recentQuery = RecentQuery(0, query, RetrofitInit.supportedLanguages.first[languageIndex], System.currentTimeMillis())
                databaseDao.addQuery(recentQuery)

            }
        }
    }

}
```

```
package com.sbeve.jada.recyclerview_utils

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.core.text.HtmlCompat
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.sbeve.jada.databinding.QueryLayoutBinding
import com.sbeve.jada.room_utils.RecentQuery
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*

class RecentQueriesAdapter(private val dataSet: List<RecentQuery>, private val onItemClickListener: OnItemClickListener) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecentQueriesAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder(myItemView: QueryLayoutBinding, private val onItemClickListener: OnItemClickListener) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(myItemView.root), View.OnClickListener {
        init {
            myItemView.root.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        private val queryText = myItemView.queryText
        fun setQueryText(queryValue: String) {
            queryText.text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(queryValue, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
        }

        private val time = myItemView.time
        fun setTimeText(timeValue: Long) {
            time.text = SimpleDateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Date(timeValue))
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            onItemClickListener.onItemClick(adapterPosition)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val binding = QueryLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(binding, onItemClickListener)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = dataSet[position]
        holder.setQueryText(currentItem.queryText)
        holder.setTimeText(currentItem.timeDate)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = dataSet.size

    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(position: Int)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use an emulated device, or are you using a real device to test?
Is it in Debug mode or even when you just run the program?

Comment: @DominikWuttke I am using a real device but i am using the debug mode.

Comment: Run the program in normal mode and look if the problem is still the same.
If not, there is no problem, in debug mode the program just doesn't run as fast as in normal mode, maybe you already have seen in the log, that some frames are dropped.